# Java knowledge required for Ant

Tags: ant

I am a newbie to Ant, and trying to use it for custom tool (around SOA) build and deploy solution.

Do I need Java knowledge for using Ant? (I have beginner to intermediate level knowledge).

Comment: Ant is not written in java so I'm going to go with "No".  Review the FAQ to explain why these sorts of questions are to be downvoted and or closed/removed: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Ant is written in java though.  You just don't need to know any to use it.

Answer (score 1):

ANT is written in java, however, you don't need to know any java to use it.  It makes use of XML to describe build processes and dependencies.